# collect return/exit status of process using system call in Linux

Tags: c

I am trying to collect the return status of process launched through call `system()`.
**sample** is the child process with return status of 100, that i want to  collect in **launcher**.
But what i am getting is a different value 256 for `exit(1);` and 51200 for `exit(200)`

Is there any relation between the exit value from **sample** and printed value from **launcher**?
How can i properly collect exit value from child to parent.

sample.c : gcc sample.c -o sample

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <errno.h>
//extern int errno;
int main()
{
 
        printf("hello\n");
  //      errno = 100;
  //      exit(-1); or
  //      exit(1);
       exit(100);
}
```

launcher.c : parent process

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int rval ;
        rval =system("./sample");
        printf("rval from sample: %d\n", rval);
        return 0;
}
```

UPDATE 1:
Actually if i use `printf("rval from sample: %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(rval));` its working on gcc but not on my cross-compiler.

On my cross compiler if i add `exit(WEXITSTATUS(100));` in sample.c , I am getting proper value to my launcher, no need to use WEXITSTATUS in launcher.

Is that ok?

Update 2: Can anybody please let me know do we need to set errnum to be able to collect the return value of process using `system` call. because i am not getting actual return value from the called process, if i return somevalue.

what i mean is inside called process something like

```
errno = retval;
return ratval
```

and in the caller process

```
retval = system(someprocess);
WEXITSTATUS(retval);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`system` does not literally return the exit status of the other program; what it actually returns is described [in its man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/system):

> The value returned is -1 on error (e.g., `fork(2)` failed), and the return status of the command otherwise. This latter return status is in the format specified in `wait(2)`. Thus, the exit code of the command will be `WEXITSTATUS(status)`.

The exact format of the returned integer is not specified in the `wait(2)` man page. I'm not sure if it's standardized in POSIX, but one should just use the provided macros in any case.

So, presuming you don't care about error checking, this should give you the expected result:

```
    printf("rval from sample: %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(rval));
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
     printf("rval from sample: %d\n", rval);
```

To:

```
    if (rval >= 0)
        printf("rval from sample: %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(rval));
    else
        perror("Unable to launch sample");
```

Note that this is platform specific according to C. The code above should work on all POSIX systems such as Linux. POSIX says that the return from `system` must match [waitpid](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) which [must have this behavior](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).